# I need, if possible, a regex that matches the following and how do i test it using javascript or a node js package

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

**any digit or uppercase letter(5 of these) followed by the character '?', or, any digit or uppercase letter(6 of these) followed by the optional character '?'**

For example, if i have:
AA54ZG - should match
AA54ZG? - should match
AA54Z? - should match
aA54ZG - shouldn't match
?A54ZG - shouldn't match
AA54Z - shouldn't match

and so on...(i can provide more examples if you feel like necessary)

Comment: try to do it by yourself https://regex101.com/

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: your description of what should match makes no sense.

Comment: This website is not a code-writing service. This is a relatively simple regular expression that you can write yourself after following some basic regular expression tutorials. Look up character classes, anchors and repetition on this site: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: ([0-9A-Z]{5}\?|[0-9A-Z]{6}\??)

Comment: @FelixKling Well i only know how to do 5 or 6 character which are numbers or upercase but idk how to include the '?' charater or separate the regex for 5 and for 6 characters

Comment: @JoaoFernandes In the future, post at least what you've tried. Even if it's wrong and getting you the wrong result. You should show that what you've tried and where it's not working. Fredo's regex at a glance looks like it gets you most of the way there, just add another "?" after the first "?".

Comment: @FredoCorleone tyvm that-s exactly what i needed

Comment: `?` is a special character in a regex. To include a special character you need to escape it: `\?`. So *"any digit or uppercase letter(5 of these) followed by the character '?"* becomes `[0-9A-Z]{5}\?`. Now you want to match an alternative: *", or, any digit or uppercase letter(6 of these) followed by the optional character '?'"*. Alternatives are expressed via `|`. The alternative is `[0-9A-Z]{6}\??` (unescaped `?` indicates that the previous pattern is optional). Together: `[0-9A-Z]{5}\?|[0-9A-Z]{6}\??`. Of course this can be simplified, but having *something* is better than nothing.

Comment: Slightly optimized version: `[0-9A-Z]{5}(\?|[0-9A-Z]\??)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Just set the "myTest" variable to whatever you want to verify, or create a more elaborate test, if you don't trust the Regex :)

```js
const MY_REGEX = /^([A-Z0-9]{5}\?)|([A-Z0-9]{6}\??)$/

function test( str ) {
  if( MY_REGEX.test( str ) )
    document.write( str +": MATCHES<br>" );
  else
    document.write( str +": DOESN'T MATCH<br>" );
}

test( "AA54ZG" ); // MATCHES
test( "AA54ZG?" ); // MATCHES
test( "AA54Z?" ); // MATCHES
test( "aA54ZG" ); // DOESN'T MATCH
test( "?A54ZG" ); // DOESN'T MATCH
test( "AA54Z" ); // DOESN'T MATCH
```

Explanation:

[A-Z0-9]{5} : 5 (or 6) upper-case letters or digits.

\?? : optional "?" (have to escape it with \?, because ? is reserved for "optional")

\? : required "?"

Comment: It will fail for the last case AA54Z

Comment: @Ciabaros: It doesn't contradict: Either 5 characters followed by a `?` or 6 characters *optionally* followed by a `?`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you're right. That's why I removed the comment right after I posted it. The current solution handles all his cases and spec.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one i came up with, it works for the examples given by you:

```
(?:^[A-Z0-9]{6}\??$)|(?:^[A-Z0-9]{5}\?$)
```

Check out here: https://regex101.com/r/HP0JH9/2

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the same (but will match in fewer steps).

```
[\dA-Z]{5}(?:\?|[\dA-Z]\??)
```

- `[\dA-Z]{5}`: 5x uppercase or digit
- `(?:\?|[\dA-Z]\??)`: Followed by either a question mark, or another upper/digit and optional question mark.  The `?:` just makes it a non-capture group.

Depending on your use case, add `^` and `$` to the beginning and end respectively to validate a whole string.

https://regex101.com/r/jPv3w7/1